# Laravel 5.2 Heroku Deployment Failed to install system packages

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-5, composer-php

I am trying to deploy Laravel 5.2 project to heroku but I am getting the following error

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bootstrapping...
-----> Installing platform packages...
!     ERROR: Failed to install system packages.

   Your platform requirements (for runtimes and extensions) could
   not be resolved to an installable set of dependencies, or a
   repository was unreachable.

   Full error information from installation attempt:

   > Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions
   > 
   > Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
   > Nothing to install or update
   > Generating autoload files

   Please verify that all requirements for runtime versions in
   'composer.lock' are compatible with the list below, and ensure
   all required extensions are available for the desired runtimes.

   For reference, the following runtimes are currently available:

   PHP:  7.1.10, 7.1.9, 7.1.8, 7.1.3, 7.1.2, 7.1.1, 7.0.24, 
   7.0.23, 7.0.22, 7.0.17, 7.0.16, 7.0.15, 5.6.31, 5.6.30, 
   5.5.38
   HHVM: 3.5.1

   For a list of supported runtimes & extensions on Heroku, please
   refer to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
!     Push failed
```

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1",
        "components/jquery": "2.1.4",
        "components/jqueryui": "1.11.4",
        "kodeine/laravel-acl": "^0.1.3",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I ran have tried to deploy about a couple of dozens time after using composer install, composer update, composer update --lock and I even deleted the composer.lock file and ran composer update again but this error is not going anywhere. Please help!

Comment: Could you please open a support ticket? It looks like the platform install step has a lock file present. There is no situation under which that should be the case. Must be a bug, and with a ticket, I can investigate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my vendor folder was not listed in `.gitignore` files and it was being pushed along with the other files on heroku. Once I added the vendor folder to `.gitignore` everything started working seamlessly.